# What does @Ignore do to JUnit XML output?

Tags: java, junit

TeamCity seems to support displaying ignored tests but I'm trying to figure out how it determines that a testcase is ignored. Can someone provide me with XML output from a JUnit test with @Ignore("reason") as an example?

Comment: Have you *actually* tried this? If all you want is the XML output, why not create a test that is ignored and see?

Answer (score 2):

The question is answered on official JetBrains TeamCity public forum http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5442048

TeamCity provides several bundled runners that automatically report tests.
In case of custom runners tests may be not reported automatically, but if tool supports generating compatible XML report TeamCity can import tests from this report.

To import such reports from custom runners you need to use TeamCity "XML report processing" build feature.

It's Ant JUnit parser actually supports reports matching DTD retrieved from Apache Ant src.
It doesn't provide any information about tests ignoring.
So tools that generate Ant JUnit-like reports have freedom to save ignored tests in different ways.

Currently following structures are supported to mark test as ignored (different tools normally use one of them):

- `...<testcase executed="false"...>...`
- `...<testcase...> <skipped/></testcase>...`
- `...<testcase status="ignored"...>...`

No ignoring reason is supported.

Comment: You should consider quoting the salient points from the thread in your answer. A year from now that thread could be gone or become very hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Well the `@Ignore("reason")` just marks the test as ingored as far as junit is concerned, and the "reason" is a human readable text for the ignore reason. Depending on what JUnit runner you use, the test might just be skipped completly, it might be skipped and counted as ignored (such as tests: x failed, y skipped, etc), or it might actually display that human readable texxt when running the suite.

For example, when I run my unit tests with maven (via mvn test) I only get a count of the skipped (`@Ignore` annotated) JUnit tests, the "reason" text is not displayed:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running service.impl.DepartmentServiceStatefulTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.1 sec
Running model.criteria.CriteriaAPITest
```

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified. What does the XML output file look like?

Answer (score 0):

JUnit ignores tests that are annotated with `@Ignore`. There's no output generated. I have never used TeamCity, but it seems it is reading the unit test files, and displays information on ignored tests.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the status is being passed through [build messages](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ImportingXMLReports).